# wordpress plugin to include files

Tags: wordpress

I created a code for wordpress plugin to include files in head. I don't have good knowledge but after googling i created it....but sure that code is not correct

```
add_action ('init', 'ajp_header_init');
add_action('wp_head','ajp_instance_code');
//This function includes the required css and js files
function ajp_header_init()
{
if ($directories[count($directories)-1] == 'mu-plugins' )
define ('AJP_PLUGIN_URL', content_url().'/'.$plugin_dir);
else
define ('AJP_PLUGIN_URL', rtrim(content_url().'/plugins/'.plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)), '/'));
wp_register_script('Jquery Adaptive Plugin',AJP_PLUGIN_URL.'/lib/jquery.adaptivate.min.js',false);
wp_register_script('Jquery Adaptive Plugin',AJP_PLUGIN_URL.'/lib/jquery.adaptivate.js',false);
wp_register_style('Jquery Adaptive Style',AJP_PLUGIN_URL.'/css/adaptive.css',false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('Jquery Adaptive Plugin');
wp_enqueue_style('Jquery Adaptive Style');
}

function ajp_instance_code()
{
echo"
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('html').adaptivate({
'widths': [240, 320, 480, 640, 768, 960, 1024, 1280, 1440, 1600, 1920, 2400],
'format': 'width_{operator}_{width}',
'orientationFormat': 'orientation_{orientation}'
});
</script>
";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you sure the code is not correct? What is not working? What errors have you received? Please read the guidelines on asking questions.

Some tips.

- The slugs for [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)/[style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) should be that - put them in lowercase and swap the spaces for -
- jQuery is loaded in noConflict mode (for good reason) by default. This means you should use 'jQuery' rather than '$' for your selectors.
- It's generally better to put your scripts in their own file and enqueue them like the others (that removes the need for the wp_head call.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [THIS PAGE](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes/#.Ubrg4_lbl8E) for a correct script implementation and try to use this code for define paths:

```
plugins_url('lib/jquery.adaptivate.min.js',__FILE__)
```

This is an example of a plugin file for colorbox script implementation:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_colorbox' );
function load_colorbox() {
    wp_register_script('jquery-colorbox', plugins_url('js/jquery.colorbox-min-1.4.17.js',__FILE__),array( 'jquery' ),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-colorbox-handler', plugins_url('js/jquery.colorbox-handler.js',__FILE__),array( 'jquery-colorbox' ),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-colorbox-style-theme', plugins_url('css/theme5/colorbox.css', __FILE__) );
}
```